# AppTransparencyTracking not working in Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Since SwiftUI doesnt have a Appdelegate file, I tried adding it through App.swift file.

However, it still doesnt work. What am i missing ?

imported the libraries

```
import AppTrackingTransparency
import AdSupport

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {func requestIDFA() {
      ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
        // Tracking authorization completed. Start loading ads here.
        // loadAd()
      })
      }
```

Then called the appdelegate under @main

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {

@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function. You have a call function inside another function so the `requestIDFA` never calls.

Put your `requestIDFA()` function out side the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and call inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        requestIDFA()
        return true
    }
    
    func requestIDFA() {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
            // Tracking authorization completed. Start loading ads here.
            // loadAd()
        })
    }
}
```

Note: Make sure you have an added key to your Info.plist.

```
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your reason, why you want to track the user</string>
```

Comment: Thanks ! That works like a charm. I am wondering if I wish to add more functions should I put it the same way ?

Comment: @vinny just add other function in the same way.